# Codename one - create virtual keyboard

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-8

am creating a codename one mobile app and i have a form where the user should key in a 4 digit PIN send to their number, now am asking whether their is a way i can create the keyboard part and not let them use their own keyboard....
I want to achieve something like this,

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert here but can't you create that "keyboard" from a bunch of buttons and have the pin input not be actual input fields but rather labels/elements that just display the input? If there is no input field on the screen there's nothing to use their own keyboard on :)

Comment: are you simply saying its impossible??

Comment: No, I was trying to say don't use any input fields that require a keyboard. That way the user's keyboard should not be displayed and even if they'd want to use it they couldn't. Just use buttons, labels etc. for that screen.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with what @Thomas suggested. It's easy to popup the native keyboard but it seems you want to create your own. Why not just use buttons? You don't need a text field or anything.